# request for a member in which is of non class type c++

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I am striving to test every function in this class and I cannot test the function that will assign a numerator and denominator to the constructor that takes no arguments here is my code. I get this error request for a member 'numerator' in 'first' which is of non class type 'Rational'

```
#include "Rational.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "GCD.h"
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

Rational:: Rational()
{
    myNumerator = 1;
    myDenominator = 1;
}

Rational:: Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    assert(denominator != 0);
    myNumerator = numerator;
    myDenominator = denominator;
    reduce();
}

Rational:: Rational(const Rational &r)
{
    myNumerator = r.myNumerator;
    myDenominator = r.myDenominator;
}
const Rational& Rational :: operator = (const Rational &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        myNumerator = rhs.myNumerator;
        myDenominator = rhs.myDenominator;
        return rhs;
    }
}

int Rational:: numerator(int a) const
{
    myNumerator = a;
    return myNumerator;
}
int Rational:: denominator(int b) const
{
    myNumerator = b;
    return myDenominator;
}
void Rational:: reduce()
{

    int commonDivisor = GCD(myNumerator, myDenominator);
    myNumerator = myNumerator / commonDivisor;
    myDenominator = myDenominator / commonDivisor;
}

Rational operator + (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs)
{
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator() + rhs.numerator() * lhs.denominator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.denominator();
    Rational sum(numerator, denominator);
    return sum;
}

Rational operator - (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs)
{
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator() + rhs.numerator() * lhs.denominator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.denominator();
    Rational difference(numerator, denominator);
    return difference;
}
Rational operator * (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs)
{
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.numerator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.denominator();
    Rational product(numerator, denominator);
    return product;
}
Rational operator / (const Rational &lhs, const Rational &rhs)
{
    int numerator = lhs.numerator() * rhs.denominator();
    int denominator = lhs.denominator() * rhs.numerator();
    Rational product(numerator, denominator);
    return product;
}


ostream& operator << (ostream & os, const Rational &r)
{
    os << r.numerator() << "/" << r.denominator();
    return os;
}

istream& operator >> (istream &is, Rational &r)
{
    char divisionSymbol;
    int numerator = 0, denominator = 0;

    is >> numerator >> divisionSymbol >> denominator;
    assert(divisionSymbol == '/');
    assert(denominator != 0);
    Rational number(numerator, denominator);
    r = number;
    return is;
}

    #include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rational first(), second(75, 350), third(13, 55);
    Rational fourth(second);
    cout << first << endl << second << endl << third << endl << fourth <<endl;

    first.numerator(3)const;
    first.denominator(5)const;

    cout << first;
}
```

Comment: When I try your code, I get many different errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c17bfa49742f80d6

Comment: Yours is caused by the "Most Vexing Parse", namely C++ thinks `First` is a function that returns a `Rational`.

Answer (score 2):

`Rational first();` is parsed as a function declaration. it is known as [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

You may use `Rational first;`
And in C++11, you may also use `Rational first{};`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to mark your functions as `const` if you're going to modify your member variables. It's a promise that you *won't* modify `*this` and you do so anyway. So simply remove it. You also provide `const` "getters" anyway.

```
int numerator(int a);
int numerator() const {return myNumerator;}
int denominator(int b);
int denominator() const {return myDenominator;}
int Rational:: numerator(int a)
{
    // ..
}
int Rational:: denominator(int b)
{
    // ..
}
```

Your copy assignment operator also doesn't make sense. I suggest changing it:

```
if (this == &rhs)
{
    return *this;
}
myNumerator = rhs.numerator();
myDenominator = rhs.denominator();
return *this;
```

Now for the error others pointed out, your compiler happily warns that `empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration`. Simply remove the parentheses or replace them with brackets `{}` in C++11 mode. Also, you don't need the `const` keyword when calling a `const` member function.

```
Rational first, second(75, 350), third(13, 55);
first.numerator(3);
first.denominator(5);
```

Comment: I still don't understand